# docker-compose args from file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a bunch of services that need the same arguments (to build a container). In cases where this is an environment, then it is easier here, there is an env_file directive, thanks to which you can reuse all of them in other services. How do I do the same for arguments? Copying and pasting a bunch of arguments that refer to environment variables in a heap of services is not very convenient. It would be much more convenient to use one file.

```
  workers:
    container_name: workers
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ../some_app
      args:
        - RUNNING_MODE=workers
        - EMAIL_HOST=$EMAIL_HOST
        - EMAIL_USER=$EMAIL_USER
        - EMAIL_PASSWORD=$EMAIL_PASSWORD
        - EMAIL_PORT=$EMAIL_PORT
```

And there are more than 10 such services (which need mail) in my docker-compose. It would be great if there was a derivative like this:

```
  workers:
    container_name: workers
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ../some_app
      args:
        - RUNNING_MODE=workers
      args_from_file:
        - some/file/path
```

I could use the env_file. But the architecture of my services does not allow building configs in the ENTRYPOINT

Comment: Can you give some examples of what these are?  Do they _need_ to be configurable, or can you hard-code these values in the Dockerfiles?  (Examples: user IDs, ports, and filesystem paths can all be safely hard-coded.)

Comment: None of the settings you included in the edited question should be `ARG`s.  You shouldn't need to rebuild your image because a password changed, and you don't want `docker history` of the image to be able to retrieve the username/password.

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Yes I could use the env_file. But the architecture of my services does not allow building configs in the ENTRYPOINT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting it wrong. You want **runtime** configuration, no build time.

all these

```
        - RUNNING_MODE=workers
        - EMAIL_HOST=$EMAIL_HOST
        - EMAIL_USER=$EMAIL_USER
        - EMAIL_PASSWORD=$EMAIL_PASSWORD
        - EMAIL_PORT=$EMAIL_PORT
```

should be `env`, and then you can configure them the way that better suits your needs. Ideally with different `.env` files, but that's up to you.